# Protractor: how to disable marionette debug mode?

Tags: debugging, protractor, firefox-marionette

here is my protractor config

```
exports.config = {
  rootElement: '[ng-app="myapp"]',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['./assets/e2e/**/*protractor.js'],
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  baseUrl: 'https://localhost/',
  allScriptsTimeout: 20000,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000,
  },
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    marionette: true,
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
      args: ['--headless'],
    },
  },
}
```

And my output log is crowded by debug messages like so

```
04:25:15 1544779515528  Marionette  DEBUG   [2147483649] Received DOM event beforeunload for https://localhost/login
04:25:18 1544779518273  Marionette  DEBUG   [2147483649] Received DOM event pagehide for https://localhost/login
04:25:30 [32m.[0m1544779531073    Marionette  DEBUG   [2147483649] Canceled page load listener because no navigation has been detected
04:25:31 [32m.[0m1544779532320    Marionette  DEBUG   [2147483649] Canceled page load listener because no navigation has been detected
```

How to get rid of those DEBUG messages, please?

Answer (score 0):

try with adding log property:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    marionette: true,
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
      args: ['--headless'],
      log: {
        level: 'info'
      }
    },
  },
```